# Generating nested observations with purrr

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'd like to generate several densities parameterized by other columns in a dataframe.  Here is some code so far:

```
library(tidyverse)

a = c(2,3,4)
b = c(10,11,10)

params = expand.grid(a, b)

bdens = function(a, b){
    dens =  dbeta(x = seq(0,1,0.01), shape1 = a, shape2  = b)
    return(dens)
  }
```

How can I use purrr an dplyr to create nested observations in the way I've described?

Comment: which function you want to apply?  Something like `pmap_dbl(setNames(params, c('x', 'size')), dbinom, prob = 0.5)`

Comment: @akrun darn, I see I wrote binomial, I meant beta.  I'll change by post.

Comment: Which is the function used for that

Comment: @akrun dbeta is the beta density

Comment: dbeta have parameters `dbeta(x, shape1, shape2, ncp = 0, log = FALSE)`.  The data you provided have only two parameters.  Are those shape1 and shape2..  It is not clear to me.

Comment: Yes, the parameters are the shape1 and shape2 parameters.  The other parameters have defaults, so I don't touch them.

Comment: What is `x` here?  It should be provided

Comment: @akrun I've edited my post to be more clear.

Comment: Based on your function `pmap(setNames(params, c('a', 'b')), bdens)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we provide the parameters with the argument names of the function, we can pass it on `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
set.seed(24)
params$dbetacol <- pmap_dbl(c(list(x = rnorm(9)), 
              setNames(params, c('shape1', 'shape2'))), dbeta)
```

NOTE: Here the `x` was created as the OP didn't provide the details about 'x'

#### Update

Based on the OP's function, we can apply the `pmap` on the function

```
lst <- pmap(setNames(params, c('a', 'b')), bdens)
```

returns a `list` of `vector`s with `length` equal to the number of rows of the 'params' dataset i.e. for each pair of `shape` arguments from each row, the density of beta distributed is calculated for the same 'x' values i.e. 101 elements (`seq(0, 1, 0.01)`)

```
length(lst)
#[1] 9
lengths(lst)
#[1] 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101 101
```